# How to define id range (T1..T20) via patterns in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xsd-1.1

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="size" type="PatternType" />
  <xs:simpleType name="PatternType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">                              
      <xs:pattern value="[T][0-9]{1,2}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

I need to create a pattern for track Id T1, T2 etc and want to limit upto T20.  But if I follow the pattern  `<xs:pattern value="[T][0-9]{1,2}"/>`, it allows T99 also.  Do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The following XSD will allow `size` to have values of `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, ... `T20`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="size" type="PatternType"/>
  <xs:simpleType name="PatternType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">                              
      <xs:pattern value="T1?\d"/>
      <xs:pattern value="T20"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

In XSD 1.1 of course you can write

```
<xs:assertion test="number(substring-after($value)) = 1 to 20"/>
```